# Ouerying an object inside ravendb document

Tags: ravendb

There is a doubt as of how to query or retrieve a value from an object stored in an document as follows in raven db.

```
class User
{
       public String Id { get; set; }
       public AccountType AccountType { get; set; }Servicetax
       public String MainAccountMobileNo { get; set; }
       public UserStatus Status { get; set; }
       public String EmailId { get; set; }
       public String DisplayName { get; set; }
       public Object User { get; set; }
}
```

Here i am storing three different types of classes into the object User.
Say Customer,Retailer and Trader.

```
Customer

{
           public String Name{ get; set; }
           public String Address { get; set; }
           public String MobileNo { get; set; }
           public String EmailId { get; set; }
}
```

Retailer

```
{
           public String Name{ get; set; }
           public String Address { get; set; }
           public String MobileNo { get; set; }
           public String EmailId { get; set; }
}
```

Trader

```
{
           public String Name{ get; set; }
           public String Address { get; set; }
           public String MobileNo { get; set; }
           public String EmailId { get; set; }
}
```

Now is it possible to retrieve results based on the Customer's class detail?
That is now i want to retrieve All the Customers based on Address in the customer class, So how will i do it? How to typecast the object user in the query to type customer.
Thanks.[image: Image of my document storage]

The user object in the document can store any type of class's object like account info trader in the above image. So how can i query from the object type that cannot is not definite and changing.

`var Result = sess.Query<UserAccountInfo>().Where(x => x.AccountType == usertype && ((AccountInfoCustomer)x.User).Customerstatus == CustomerStatus.Pending);`

> This is the query that's been tried and this is the exception that's been caught
>    {"Url:
>   \"/indexes/dynamic/UserAccountInfos?query=AccountType%253ADistributor%2520AND%2520User).Customerstatus%253APending&start=0&pageSize=128&aggregation=None\"\r\n\r\nSystem.ArgumentException:
>   The field ')_Customerstatus' is not indexed, cannot query on fields
>   that are not indexed\r\n   at
>   Raven.Database.Indexing.Index.IndexQueryOperation.AssertQueryDoesNotContainFieldsThatAreNotIndexes()

Comment: Yes it is possible, but I don't see the Customer class referenced in your User Class.

Comment: After you fix your classes to show us how you are relating them, also show what query you have tried so we understand your intent.

Comment: I am storing customer class in the object type that i have mentioned as user inside the user class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here was the build of raven db. i was using the older build after changing it to newer version the query

```
var Result = sess.Query<UserAccountInfo>().Where(x => x.AccountType == usertype && ((AccountInfoCustomer)x.User).Customerstatus == CustomerStatus.Pending);
```

works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Your classes are not very DRY. Consider this instead:

```
public abstract class Person
{
    public string Name{ get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string MobileNumber { get; set; }
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
}

public class Customer : Person {}
public class Retailer : Person {}
public class Trader : Person {}
```

Then, in your User class replace

```
public Object User { get; set; }
```

With this:

```
public Person Person { get; set; }
```

That way, you can store an instance of any of the 3 derived types. I wouldn't call the property `User` given that the containing class is called `User` and `User.User` could get confusing to anyone having to understand your code.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.. but this is not the solution I'm expecting i have had those classes as sample there its not my real one. I would appreciate if you actually solve my problem. which is querying the object which is stored in an document.

Comment: It's difficult to help you solve your problem if you don't actually post the code that you're having a problem with. The error that you're seeing cannot be thrown by the code you have posted.